# Test method with a mock response, without create data

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'm testing with unittest a method, createData, which create something in my database.

```
def createData(self, content):
    logging.info("Creating data...")
    request = requests.post(self.url, data=content)
    if request.status_code == 201:
        logging.info("Data created")
    else:
        logging.error("Data not created")
            
    return request
```

So I created two tests : one where I fail in creating data, with `self.assertNotEqual(201, badRequest.status_code)` and another where I succeed, with `self.assertEqual(201, goodRequest.status_code)`. Of course, after, I delete this data.

I want to make this test without create any data. So I mock the response like that :

```
import unittest, logging
from data import Data as data
from unittest.mock import Mock

class TestData(unittest.TestCase):

    def testCreateDataSuccess(self):
        mock_response = Mock()
        mock_response.status_code = 201
        with self.assertLogs() as captured:
            data.createData(data, goodContent).return_value = mock_response
            self.assertEqual(201, mock_response.status_code)
            self.assertEqual(captured.records[1].levelname, 'INFO')
```

However, despite mock, a data is created in my database. Could you tell me what I didn't understand ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you post the entire test? `createData(badContent).return_value = mock_response` is probably not doing what you expect it's doing

Comment: Yes probably, I'm a beginner with Python AND with test -_-'

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of your test: including your imports at the top of the test file. How long is the test file? Can you just post the whole thing?

Comment: Actually it was just an indentation mistake, deeply sorry ! But you're right, mock is not doing what I thought because there is again a data created...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocks are typically applied using `mock.patch`. What you want to mock is the response from `requests.post`, not the response from `createData`. Figuring out where to mock can be pretty tricky. This guide can help (https://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/)

You will probably need to rework how you import your code-under-test in order to be able to mock in the correct place.

```
import unittest, logging
import data  # We are importing the entire module. This will let us patch in the correct location
from unittest.mock import Mock

class TestData(unittest.TestCase):

    def testCreateDataSuccess(self):
        mock_response = Mock()
        mock_response.status_code = 201
        # using mock.patch, we can replace the response from requests.post with our mock value. `requests` is imported in the `data` module so we mock `data.requests`
        with mock.patch(data.requests.post, return_value=mock_response):
            with self.assertLogs() as captured:
                data.Data.createData(data, goodContent)
                # self.assertEqual(201, mock_response.status_code) This line does not actually do anything - it's just testing that our mock has the status code we set. But we already know that, because we set it just a few lines ago. 
                self.assertEqual(captured.records[1].levelname, 'INFO')
```

Comment: We posted in same time :) Thank you for this explanation ! 
However, since I'm setting the status_code (and you're right, it's stupid to test it few lines after...), if there wasn't any logging.info how could test the result ?

Comment: I'm glad you got patching working! For testing the result, you would want to test anything that happens in that `if` block. So, if you create a data record in the `if` block, you would test that the data record was created.

If you call an external library in the `if block function, you can mock out that function as well and use `assert_called_with` to test that it got called correctly without actually calling out to an external service

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found how to resolve this problem : using patch decorator.
I guess it  "defuses" requests post in data, substituting response with the configured mock

```
import unittest, logging
from data import Data as data
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestData(unittest.TestCase):
    
    @patch('data.requests.post')
    def testCreateDataSuccess(self, mock_post):
        mock_post.return_value.status_code = 201
        with self.assertLogs() as captured:
            response = data.createData(data, goodContent)
            self.assertEqual(201, response.status_code)
            self.assertEqual(captured.records[1].levelname, 'INFO')
```